# Apache POI autosize feature is not working with wrapped text (new line)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to auto size a column that is rotated 90 degree has a new line in the value, but seems autosize is not expanding the width of the cell if it contains a new line (only the part before the new line appears and the other part is hidden) as in the code below, is there any workaroudn for this

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    
    String value ="This is long text with new line ... \n this is the second line";
    
    XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setRotation((short)90);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    
    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
    
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    

    workbook.getSheetAt(0).autoSizeColumn(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This kinda makes sense to me because of the `setWrapText(true)`. According to apache-poi docs for `autoSizeColumn()`, this method

> Adjusts the column width to fit the contents

But before you call `autoSizeColumn()`, you are calling `setWrapText(true)`, which what it does is to fit all your text content inside the cell, so since the text is fit inside the cell, `autoSizeColumn()` has no work to do there because the text already fit and there is no need for the column to be widen.